# Why Controller suffix removed from URL in MVC/API application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes

In MVC/web API application controllers are suffix with **Controller** keyword.

But when any action called or rendered on browser, the URL generated in browser will remove the **Controller** suffix.

For example,
I have controller `HomeController` with action `UserList`.

When this action rendered in browser, the URL generated in browser will be looks like `http://localhost:123/Home/UserList`

So I want to know that from where Controller suffix is removed from browser's URL?

Comment: that is by design in the framework for convention-based routing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ASP.NET MVC uses [Convention over Configuration](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/dotnet/asp-net/asp-net-mvc-controllers-and-conventions/). MVC identifies the right Controller and its Action method from the URL using the Route data. More details about MVC pipeline/lifecycle are [here](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/wp-content/plugins/download-attachments/includes/download.php?id=59902) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/lifecycle-of-an-aspnet-mvc-5-application).

It would be good to take a look at the DefualtControllerFactory of ASP.NET Core in [github](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/master/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core/Controllers/DefaultControllerFactory.cs).